# Make DIV same width as inline-blocked divs?

Tags: html, css

I have the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/sSqxn/2/

The month `divs` are using `inline-block` in order to be side by side. They can each be varying widths. The browser will automatically scroll horizontally to accomodate their total width.

Right now, the blue div is only ever the width of the browser window.  Is it possible to make the blue div the full width of all the `month` divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `width: 100%` from your `.months` rule.

```
.months {
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```